# Limit on requests per hour for foursquare Userless Venues Api

Tags: foursquare

Is there a way to go above the 5000 requests per hour for the userless venue api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation at FourSquare](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues.html);

> The platform offers all of this without requiring end user
>   authentication and is available at high rate limits (5,000 requests
>   per hour, with more available on request by email to
>   api@foursquare.com).